# How to cancel popState in certain condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The `popState` event will be triggered when the url has changed (either back or forward). And recently I have noticed that, for example, in `http://www.example.com/`:

```
<a href="#anchor">Top</a>
```

will also trigger `popState`, causing the page to "reload".
 How can I know that if it is the same url and only the `#` part has changed?

```
$(window).bind("popstate",function(){
    swap(location.href);
})
```

In the example, when you click on "Top" link (see above), the page will go to `#anchor`, but also it will trigger `popState` and causes reloading, which is I do not expect.

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't find anything from the event to determine if that this was just an anchor change, so I had to keep track of it myself with code like the following:

```
function getLocation() {
  return location.pathname + location.search;
}

var currentLocation = getLocation();

$(function() {
  $(window).on("popstate", function() {
    var newLocation = getLocation();
    if(newLocation != currentLocation) {
      // DO STUFF
    }
    currentLocation = newLocation;
  });
})
```

The location is stored without the hash, so when the popstate fires due to clicking on the link with the anchor, the getLocation method will return the same result as before and the code to swap the page won't happen.

To make sure you keep track of the current location properly, you also need to update the variable whenever you change the state with pushState() or replaceState()

Answer (score 0):

You could be checking `window.location.hash` to see what `#` type of anchor is added to it and take the appropriate action.

Also, by checking `window.onhashchange` you can distinguish between full URL changes in `window.location.href` or just hash changes.

Example:

```
window.onhashchange = function()
{
    console.log('Hash change:' + window.location.hash);
}
```

Comment: But how can I combine it with `popState`?

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history): `"Note that pushState() never causes a hashchange event to be fired, even if the new URL differs from the old URL only in its hash."` Seems not to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is all quite simple. What you have to do is to make hash not to get added to the browser address bar.

For this basically you have to add `click` event handler, in there check if the link is the one you want to avoid firing popstate on hash change and, if yes, prevent default behaviour with `event.preventDefault()`.

I just wrote an answer with code example and detailed explanations on the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56035631/6597265).